# Elasticsearch-kafka-river plugin issue

Tags: json, elasticsearch, apache-kafka

I am trying to pass data from Kafka to Elasticsearch and then to Kibana. I am using kafka-river plugin as mentioned in this link:[Elasticsearch-river-kafka plugin](https://github.com/mariamhakobyan/elasticsearch-river-kafka)

After starting Kafka Zookeeper, server and producer, I am giving data as {"test":"one"}

Then start elasticsearch. I am getting the following error in Kafka:

```
[2016-02-04 00:05:00,094] ERROR Closing socket for /192.168.1.9 because of error (kafka.network.Processor)
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:375)
at kafka.utils.Utils$.read(Utils.scala:380)
at kafka.network.BoundedByteBufferReceive.readFrom(BoundedByteBufferReceive.scala:54)
at kafka.network.Processor.read(SocketServer.scala:444)
at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:340)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And, in elasticsearch the following error:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('S' (code 83)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
```

Also, I see this in elasticsearch logs: 
`[2016-02-04 00:14:31,340][WARN ][river.routing            ] [ISAAC] no river _meta document found after 5 attempts`

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of rivers is deprecated in elastic search, it adds performance issues. Why dont you look at using the LogStash Kafka plugin for same thing. You can find out more about it at https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-kafka-intro